# 2D slider "coverflow" framwork/how to make suggestion (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks, coverflow

I want to implement in my app 2D "coverflow" like in this sketch:

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3amnA.png)

That you can swipe left or right to switch the category.
I'm looking for a framework or a tutorial for making it.

Does anybody know a framework/have an idea how to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: A UIScrollView with paging enabled will do the trick.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of code on how I do it?

Comment: Check out this project and the example code it provides: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Hope it helps.